# Meaning of pre-superscript in group theory

Tags: notation

Is pre-superscript a standard notation for something?  I've encountered it in the following:

$$(a,g)(b,h) = (a + {}^gb + f(g,h), gh).$$

This was given in relation to a formula for the multiplication on the abelian set $A$ with extension $G$ as $A$ X $G$.

Comment: may be conjugation

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261660/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-conjugation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${}^g b$ is, in general, shortand for $g$ *acting on* $b$ from the left.
Often, this means the left conjugation action $gbg^{-1}$ (as opposed to $b^g = g^{-1} bg$, the right conjugation action). If $G$ and $A$ are separate groups, though, and $G$ has a distinguished action on $A$, then ${}^gb$ might be used instead of $g \cdot b$ in this action.

---

I hope this helps ^_^